# jQuery autocomplete source is null

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

After user select state and city, an Ajax is fired to retrieve data from server. Only then, I want to allow them to search through the results using `jQuery UI autocomplete`.
I fill a variable named `agenciesBasedOnLocation` in the Ajax response (so far so good). But when I add this to `source`  of the `autcomplete`, it's not working. 
The error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.source is not a function

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
var agenciesBasedOnLocation;
$('#cityId').on('change',function(){
    var cityId = $('#toBeCollected').children().find('.cityId').val();
    var provinceId = $('#toBeCollected').children().find('.provinceId').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: window.baseUrl + "/getAllAgenciesByLocation",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {"cities_id":cityId,"provinces_id":provinceId,"agency_groups_id":$('#aGroups').val()},
        success: function(result)
        {
            agenciesBasedOnLocation = result;                               
        }
    });       
});

$("#autoComplete").autocomplete({
    source: agenciesBasedOnLocation,
    select: function( event, ui ) 
    {
        $("#autoComplete").val( ui.item.last_name + " - " + ui.item.mobile);
        alert(ui.item.id);            
        return false;
    }    
})
.data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li>" )
        .append( "<span>" + item.label + 
            "</span><br><span style='font-size: 80%;'>Desc: " + item.mobile + "</span>" +
            "<br><span style='font-size: 60%;'>Other: " + item.last_name + "</span>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
};
</script>
```

Comment: You will want to set the Source inside the AJAX Success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Autocomplete is initialized before the AJAX call is performed, you need to update or set the Source when the data is available. Consider the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
var agenciesBasedOnLocation;
$('#cityId').on('change',function(){
  var cityId = $('#toBeCollected').children().find('.cityId').val();
  var provinceId = $('#toBeCollected').children().find('.provinceId').val();
  $.ajax({
    url: window.baseUrl + "/getAllAgenciesByLocation",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      "cities_id":cityId,"provinces_id":provinceId,"agency_groups_id":$('#aGroups').val()
    },
    success: function(result) {
      agenciesBasedOnLocation = result;
      $("#autoComplete").autocomplete("option", "source", agenciesBasedOnLocation);                             
    }
  });       
});

$("#autoComplete").autocomplete({
  source: [],
  select: function(event, ui) {
    $("#autoComplete").val( ui.item.last_name + " - " + ui.item.mobile);
    alert(ui.item.id);            
    return false;
  }    
});
.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
  return $( "<li>" )
    .append("<span>" + item.label + 
    "</span><br><span style='font-size: 80%;'>Desc: " + item.mobile + "</span>" +
    "<br><span style='font-size: 60%;'>Other: " + item.last_name + "</span>")
    .appendTo(ul);
};
</script>
```

When we initialize Autocomplete, it has an empty array as the Source. Once the AJAX completes, the Source is updated to match the newly populated Array. Now Users can search from that array.

[Source | Autocomplete | jQuery UI API Documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)

Comment: Although I found another way, but this way sounds much easier.
The answer helped me, I hope this can solve others issues regarding autocomplete as the code represent a pretty good and simple sample of jQuery autocomplete.